# Why are mid-open/open vowels considered [- tense]?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, vowels, articulation

I found the following chart (which was taken from Donegan (1976)) on a book and something reminded me of a simple question I always had, but I never came across a definitive answer: why are some open vowels considered [-tense] counterparts of more closed vowels?

[image]

Is it only to distinguish two pairs that are near to each other and are only differentiated by the tension of keeping them more closed than the other?

Comment: Not to be too anti-tradition but the best explanation I can give is that tense/lax is bizarre, confusing categorical distinction that is relevant to a few phonologies but is phonetically baseless and could be replaced by a variety of better terms nearly everywhere it’s used in conventional pedagogy and academia.

Comment: Yes! I feel the same thing.

Comment: Is the point of the question to insult traditional phonological feature theories, or are you actually interested in understanding the theory? It seems to me that if you're unhappy with the analysis, you should just adopt whatever theory you feel makes you happiest.

Comment: worth noting that this table is also using a non-standard transcription (the +palatal +labial medias appear to be front rounded vowels so would be œ & ø in standard IPA, and I'm not even sure what the -palatal +labial -tensa baixa vowel is supposed to be

Comment: @Tristan The vowel you're confused about is definitely supposed to be equivalent to [ʊ]. Capital U is an established and relatively common substitute for the tʊrned omega/horseshoe symbol (like capital E for εpsilon), but I agree that it seems silly to use it when the writer clearly had non-Latin graphemes available.

Comment: @GrahamH. No, that’s the _alta_ (high) vowel – Tristan was, and I too am, confused about the _baixa_ (low) vowel, second from the right in the bottom row, given as ⟨ɒ⟩ just like the vowel next to it. I would definitely describe /ɒ/ as being tense, though; the IPA doesn’t have a designated symbol for its lax equivalent, but it would be something like /ɐ̱/ or /ʌ̞/.

Comment: I woudn't ask if I did not want a serious answer. What I mean is that it seems weird to me, that's why I would like to understand it. And yes, the notation is not standard IPA, but that is not the point of the question.

Comment: @Tristan The source for that table is http://www.ling.hawaii.edu/faculty/donegan/Papers/1976raising&lowering.pdf , and there the -palatal +labial -tense is an odd symbol which looks like a lowercase sigma or an o with a hook. It probably stands for /ɑ/ or /ɐ/, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you, my mistake.

Comment: @Wtrmute huh, interesting that the typesetting in the OP is so different (with the only difference between the tense and lax forms seemingly being a slightly bigger serif on the lax form). I'd definitely interpret the symbol in the source as ɑ (just in a slightly odd font), noting the parallel to how it renders ɒ.